# Trying to delete specific columns in Python 3

Tags: python, csv

I'm a python noobie writing my first productive program. The gist of my project is that I'm trying to import a CSV, split it up into a couple different CSV files by row (rows 10-100000 go to file 1, 100001-200000 go to file 2, etc.) and at some point I'd like to delete specified columns (specifically columns 5-400 that have a remainder of 1 when divided by three, but I'll add that bit in later). For now, I'm just trying to delete the first row.

```
import csv
import itertools
import ctypes

signals = open('EPcathBIO_FILTERED.csv')
csv_sig = csv.reader(signals)

csv_head = open('EPcathBIO_HEAD.csv', 'w', newline='')
cs_writer = csv.writer(csv_head, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
for row in itertools.islice(csv_sig, 180):
    print(row)
    cs_writer.writerow(row)   
csv_head.close()

csv_body = open('EPcathBIO_BODY.csv', 'w', newline='')
cs_writer = csv.writer(csv_body, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
for row in csv_sig: # itertools.islice(csv_sig, 0, 182): #restrict to start of body to the end
    cs_writer.writerow(row)

for E in csv_body:
    del E[1]
csv_body.close()  

signals.close()
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Benjamin\Documents\JPH Lab\Data\2015_02_10_19_51_55\processor.py", line 22, in <module>
for E in csv_body:
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

Thanks for your help and patience!

Comment: When you `open` a file, the result is a stream object which can only be read once, like a tape. Here you try to access a stream which has already reached "it's end"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You opened `csv_body` in `w` (write) mode.  That means you can only write data to it, you can't read data from it.  Since you can't read data from it, you can't iterate over it.  You would need to open it in `rw` (read/write) mode.  You would also need to rewind it back to the start of the file by seeking.

But even if you did that, `csv_body` is just a text file, it doesn't know how to delete an element like that.

Also, in your example, `csv_head` and `csv_body` both go from row 0 to row 180.  I assume you want `csv_head` to be up to 180 and `csv_body` to be 180 and higher.

You should really be using the `pandas` package for this.  Your whole script would be something like this (assuming you want head to end at 180 and body to start at 180):

```
import pandas as pd

signals = pd.read_csv('EPcathBIO_FILTERED.csv')
signals.iloc[180:].to_csv('EPcathBIO_HEAD.csv')
signals.iloc[:180, 1:].to_csv('EPcathBIO_BODY.csv')
```